# VPython graphs - Clearing the display so a new set of data can be shown

Tags: graph, vpython

I have a list of data that I want to be animated on the plot, I'm currently using:

```
graph1=gdots(pos = pvalues)    #pvalues is list of points

while t <= t_max:
    rate(200)
    ...    #pvalues is updated to new contain the new points
    graph1=gdots(pos = pvalues)
```

What happens here is the old points remain on the plot, so lines are traced out when I want the points to just move. I've tried deleting the graph, making it invisible, but none of it works.

```
graph1.visible = False
del graph1
```

Including the above makes no noticeable difference to the display. I've searched a lot about this, but the VPython documentation seems to be annoyingly incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very old question, however I had the same issue with vpython 7. For me, `graph1.delete()` removed the associated data points from the graph, and rescaled the axes based on the remaining data (if any). I haven't yet found a way to remove the graph axes themselves (i.e. delete the figure).